# Best method of getting the string value from the combobox to be used in database comparison

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, combobox

I have a combobox that is populated on the form load event. Of course the values are string format. They info is displayed 1-info in the combobox. I want to take that first digit and compare it to a value in my database. Based off which value it finds then populates the fields on the form. Here is what I have so far. I have been able to figure out as far as converting it back to int 32.

```
if (cmboBoxPreviousVersion.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            string[] s = cmboBoxPreviousVersion.Items[cmboBoxPreviousVersion.SelectedIndex].ToString().Split(' ');
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(s[0]);


            Item.FormatID = data.FormatID;
            Item.FormatName = data.FormatName;
            Item.FormatDescription = data.FormatDescription;
            Item.StockID = data.StockID;
            Item.PrintPlantCode = (bool)data.PrintPlantCode;
            Item.PrintWeight = (bool)data.PrintWeight;
            Item.PrintPrice = (bool)data.PrintPrice;

            rChkBoxPlantCode.Checked = Item.PrintPlantCode;
            rChkBoxPrintPrice.Checked = Item.PrintPrice;
            rChkBoxWeight.Checked = Item.PrintWeight;
            cmboBoxStock.Items.Add(Item.StockID);
            rTxtBoxDescription.Text = Item.FormatDescription;
        }
        rChkBoxPlantCode.Enabled = false;
        rChkBoxPrintPrice.Enabled = false;
        rChkBoxWeight.Enabled = false;
```

Any suggestions? Thank you before hand. If you need any other info or clarification let me know!

Added combox fill method

```
try
        {
            List<PreviousVersionData> listID = PreviousVersionData.getDatabase();
            if (listID != null)
            {
                foreach (PreviousVersionData l in listID)
                {
                    cmboBoxPreviousVersion.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", l.FormatID, l.FormatName));

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you keep numbers in combobox's id field?

Comment: @jim I use a class to run the query. I will update with method of fill

Comment: _"They info is displayed 1-info...I want to take that first digit and compare it to a value in my database."_  But you split on ' ' not '-'.  Also you are taking every character prior to the space not just the first digit.  Do you mean digit(s)?  What is the actual problem you are having.  It isn't clear to me.

Comment: Every item in combobox has both Text and Value properties. The Value is generally used to keep item's ID so you can use it for identifying the selected item.

Comment: @Harrison trying to figure out a method of filling the fields on the form with the data in the database. The separate on '-' is helpful I will do that. I am unsure of how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
int id;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(s[0], out id);
```

Now `result` has true/false if it was able to parse the value, without throwing exceptions.

Comment: Why do you use that method as opposed to mine?

Comment: @CharmingInferno TryParse will always handle exceptions, given you do not have a convertable string in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont use [ComboBox item's ID field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.value.aspx) for other purposes then better store numbers in there.